# What is a better way and how to achieve sending object from one nested component to another

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-template, angular-decorator

I'm working on simple application about products,  basically when user choose a product it should be sent to another component which would hold product.

Product is allways choosen one by one, **I am NEVER sending a LIST**! Only **item by item**!

So basically when I click on any of products in the middle of screen (*Product food 1, Product food 2, Product food 3*) it should be sent to the right part of the screen which is also separated component.

So my middle component looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products;" class="product-holder">
  <div id="product.id" class="product" [style.background]="'url('+ product.imgUrl +')'">
    <p class="product-price">{{product.mpc | number}}</p>
    <p class="product-title">{{product.title}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a typescript code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './app-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Article[];

  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._sharedService.getEventSubject().subscribe((param: any) => {
      if (param !== undefined) {
        this.theTargetMethod(param);
      }
    });
  }

  theTargetMethod(param) {
    // Here I am populating middle screen with products 
    this.products = param;
  }
}
```

And now I will post my right component which should receive product :

```
<div class="order-article">
  <div class="order-img"></div>
  <div class="order-title">
    <p>HERE I SHOULD WRITE ARTILE TITLE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="order-quantity pull-right">
    <span class="order-quantity-number">ARTICLE QUANTITY</span>
  </div>
</div>

export class ReceiptItemComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

So this 'right' component should receive clicked product from the middle, and I don't know how to do it, I red about `@Input` and `@Output` decorators and also about `services`, I guess @input and @output are right solution here because I'm sending one by one item?

But I don't know practically how to to solve this..

Any kind of help would be awesome

Thanks

AFTER fjc help:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products;" class="product-holder" (click)="addReceiptItem(article)">
  <div id="product.id" class="product" [style.background]="'url('+ product.imgUrl +')'">
    <p class="product-price">{{product.mpc | number}}</p>
    <p class="product-title">{{product.title}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see guys:

1.) I added `addReceiptItem` method

2.) This method accepts clicked product:

```
addReceiptItem(receiptItem: Product) {
    this._sharedService.addReceiptItem(receiptItem);
  }
```

3.)Injected service '`_sharedService`' and created method there called also 'addReceiptItem'

4.)In my service I created `BehaviorSubject` like this:  `private receiptItem = new BehaviorSubject<any>(undefined);`

4.)Method in a service looks like this:

```
addReceiptItem(receiptItems: Product) {
    this.arr1.push(receiptItems);
    this.receiptItem.next(this.arr1);
  }
```

This method is pushing clicked items to an array which will be send to a component that displays products

4.11) Added also method for getting data which returns BehaviorSubject:

```
getReceiptItem(): BehaviorSubject<any> {
    return this.receiptItem;
  }
```

5.)Edited Components that display products (code was posted also before doing anything - empty typescript file), and now it looks like this:

```
export class ReceiptItemComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService) { }

  receiptItems: Product[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this._sharedService.getReceiptItem().subscribe(products => this.receiptItems = products);
  }

}
```

Left is only to do destroy somehow?

Comment: Your (new) solution looks generally fine. One remark would be that you probably want to initialize your BehaviorSubject with a value (e.g. an empty array: `[]`) rather than `undefined`. If you don't want an initial value, you can just use a `Subject` instead.

Comment: @fjc what about UBSUBSCRIBING part?

Comment: Did you check the link I posted below? That explains everything you need to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of strategies to solve this. Overall, this is a state management problem: Multiple components are working on one joint state.

## Option 1: Parent Component Manages State

This might be the most simple solution.

- The parent component that holds all other components has a list of selected products.
- The child components that let the user pick a product have an @Output() EventEmitter that emits when the user picks a product. The parent component listens to that output and adds the emitted product to its list of products.
- The child components that display selected products have an @Input() array of products, based on which they display products. The parent component sets this input to its product list.

## Option 2: State Service

Quickly implemented, but much cleaner separation of concerns than #1.

- Implement an @Injectable `StateService`. It has a) a `BehaviorSubject<Product[]>` with a list of products, b) a method `addProduct(product: Product)` that adds a product to the current value of the `BehaviorSubject` and emits it.
- Each component uses that service (`constructor(stateService: StateService)`). When the user picks a product, the component calls `this.stateService.addProduct(product)`.
- Components that display products listen to changes in the service's product list: `this.stateService.products.subscribe(products => this.products = products)` and display the products accordingly.

## Option 3: Use a State Store Library

Use something like NGRX or Redux that takes care of state management for you.

Comment: Vote up! Is your advice also state service? I'm little bit afraid of services because they might be dangerous? subscribe, unsubscribe? Thanks for help!

Comment: I believe that it is the best combination of a quick and clean implementation. Plus it will force you to learn about RXJS. They're not dangerous. I have worked with multiple wild services. None has ever done me any harm (bring sausages though).

Comment: I'll read about them soon, but what about that thing unsubscribe? That should be done after subscribing? Thanks again

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription

Comment: when you said Components that display products listen to changes in the service's product list:, where should that component listen for a changes, on a ngOnInit?

Comment: Yes, onInit is normally a good place to subscribe, onDestroy to unsubsrribe

Comment: I've posted how I solved it, is that right approach? Can you please check and suggest me where to destroy this subscibe?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a productsSelected array to your ProductsComponent, into which you push selected products when selected and then pass it as an Input to your ReceiptItemComponent ( or ReceiptItemsComponent ). Don't forget of [()] -- box of bananas, two way data binding - if you are going to change the quantity in the child component but you are going to save the array in your parent component.

You could use a service also, that holds the selectedProducts as a behaviorSubject and inject it in both components. Then you have to subscribe to changes in both components to receive the updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I wrote my library RxCache for. It gives push data flow to Angular applications without having to add the complexity and ridiculous amount of boiler plate code involved in adding a store like NGRX.

https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-rxcache

Testbed on StackBlitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3yqpfe

A redo of the official ngrx example app can be seen here on StackBlitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-tsrf1f