# Angular 2+ Send data from child to parent component

Tags: angular

I have a "parent" component that contains an array of employees displayed on a list. Inside this component, there's a "detail" component that receives an "employee" object, changes it's attributes and then must send it to back to the list of employees in the parent component, but I'm struggling to find a good solution for it. I've already made a research on the internet, but couldn't find a proper solution.

Any tips?

I currently have 5 days of experience with Angular/web development, so I'm sorry if this a silly question.

Comment: did you try output property binding

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079474/what-is-a-better-way-and-how-to-achieve-sending-object-from-one-nested-component/51079735#51079735

Answer (score -1):

Check out the angular docs they are very good. I would use a event EventEmitter and input bindings.

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event